# Contar cuantas coincidencias existen en una tabla con referencia a un dato en otra tabla en postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, function

La orden es, que se señale la cantidad de cuentas que tiene cada cliente, estas se encuentran en otra tabla con la llave foránea del id del cliente, necesito hacer una función que me de como resultado el número de cuentas que tiene cada usuario.

Tengo ya esta función pero al ejecutar me cuenta las cuentas existentes y las coloca ese número en todas las filas, como puedo corregirla?

```
create or replace function cantidad_cuentas()
returns integer as
$body$
declare
cant integer;
begin
select count(*) into cant from "Cuenta" cu inner join cliente cli on (cli.id = cu.id_cliente);

return cant;
end
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pensémoslo así: tienes 100 usuarios, y cada uno tiene 3 cuentas. La consulta

```
 SELECT * FROM cuenta cu JOIN cliente cli on cli.id=cu.id_cliente
```

Devuelve 300 registros. Si no usas un `GROUP BY`, el resultado de

```
 SELECT count(*) FROM cuenta cu JOIN cliente cli on cli.id=cu.id_cliente
```

Es simplemente 300.

No estás proporcionando suficientes detalles con respecto a la función que necesitas, específicamente, cómo debiera ser la sentencia para llegar a tu resultado.

**Una manera, aunque subóptima, sería plantear la función para devolver un entero**

```
  SELECT id, cantidad_cuentas(id) as cant FROM cliente
```

O sea (como lo tienes ahora) recibiendo el id del cliente cuyas cuentas quieres contar devolver para ese registro el conteo de ese cliente solamente.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cantidad_cuentas(cliente_id int)
RETURNS int AS 
$$
DECLARE
   cant int;
BEGIN
   SELECT count(*) INTO cant FROM cuenta WHERE id_cliente = cliente_id;
   RETURN cant;
END;
$$;
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

**Si en cambio quisieras obtener de la función un set de registros, para llegar al resultado mediante**

```
 SELECT cli.id, cc.cant 
   FROM cliente cli 
   JOIN cantidad_cuentas() cc ON cli.id = cc.id_cliente
```

entonces la función no necesita parámetros, y debe devolver una tabla

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION cantidad_cuentas()
RETURNS TABLE(id_cliente int, cant int) AS
$$
BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE  'SELECT id_cliente, count(*)::int cant  from cuentas group by  id_cliente';
END
$$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```